# jQuery is it possible to concatenate two selector variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have two variables defining separate selectors, for example...

```
var parent = $('.parent');
var child = $('.child');
```

And I want to create a something like the following...

```
$(parent + child).click();
```

Which should be equivalent to doing this (if it was correct syntax)...

```
$('.parent .child').click();
```

This may not be best practice, however I am curious if it is possible. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think you mean `.parent, .child` to match both right?

Comment: Just posting on my phone.. have you tried using `||` which usually donates OR in JavaScript.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to select?

Comment: I am trying to select the child element.. But I am wondering if it is possible to do by combining variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a jQuery object to use as `context` in another selector, using [`$( selector [, context] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
var parent = $('.parent');
var child = $('.child');
$(child, parent).click(function () {

});
```

`$(child, parent)` is the equivalent of `$(".parent .child")`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D6nx2/)**.

Comment: `$(child, parent)` is the same as `parent.find(child)`, but slightly cleaner looking :-)

Comment: Yeah that is what I am looking for this works. For some reason I thought I had to use +

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.find`.

```
parent.find(child).click();
```

Comment: much better solution ;-) +1 - and now I realise my comment at the top won't work, considering they're jQuery objects and not strings!

Answer (score 0):

The title indicates that the OP wanted to know whether it is possible to concatenate two selections which have been bound to variables (at least others landing here will be looking for that) a la jQuery's `.add()`. Assuming the implied nesting relationship of `child` and `parent` is a red herring, you can use the concatenation like:

```
parent.add(child).click();
```